# Turn on Wifi and connect to a protected SSID on ios with react native

Tags: ios, network-programming, react-native-ios

I am working on IOT project with react native in which Phone must connect to a protected WiFi(no internet connection). I should programmatically turn on WiFi and connect to the protected ssid. So, I used the following library:  https://github.com/JuanSeBestia/react-native-wifi-reborn.
On android, I have full control on device and everything works like a charm. On the other hand, on ios, I can't turn wifi on and even after that user turns the wifi on, it seems defined functions in library like connectToProtectedSSID just doesn't work.
Any advice would be appreciated.

P.s. I exactely followed the document in the library including location access in both platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the solution for both platforms:

**iOS:**

with the following approach app will turn on WIFI and connect to the specific SSID (at least for iOS 13):

You should add these capabilities to your app :

1. Access WiFi Information
2. Hotspot Configuration ( **this is missed in the README !** )
3. (iOS 13) "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage
   Description" or "Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage
   Description" in Settings -> info

> ```
>  import WifiManager from "react-native-wifi-reborn";
>  ConnectToNetwork = async () => {
>        WifiManager.connectToProtectedSSID("YourSSIDName", "YourPassword", false)
>                 .then(
>                   () => {
>                     //console.log("connectToProtectedSSID successfully!");
>                       },
>                   (reason) => {
>                   //console.log("connectToProtectedSSID failed!");
>                   //console.log(reason);
>               }
>               );
>   }
> ```

**Android:**

Don't forget to turn on location!

disconnecting from the current SSID and connecting to the desired one:

```
import RNAndroidLocationEnabler from 'react-native-android-location-enabler';
import WifiManager from "react-native-wifi-reborn";
     ConnectToNetwork() {
    WifiManager.setEnabled(true);
    WifiManager.disconnect();
    //WifiManager.forceWifiUsage(true);
    PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        title: '',
        message:'',
        buttonNegative: '',
        buttonPositive: '',
      },
      ).then((granted) => {
        
        //console.log(granted);
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) 
        {
            //console.log("granted");        
            RNAndroidLocationEnabler.promptForEnableLocationIfNeeded({interval: 10000, fastInterval: 5000})
            .then(data => {
              WifiManager.connectToProtectedSSID("YourSSIDName", "YourPassword", false)
              .then(
                () => {
                  //console.log("connectToProtectedSSID successfully!");
                    },
                (reason) => {
                //console.log("connectToProtectedSSID failed!");
                //console.log(reason);
            }
            );
                //console.log("location enabled");
                //WifiManager.connectToProtectedSSID("", "", false)
             WifiManager.getCurrentWifiSSID().then(
              ssid => {
                if(ssid =="YourSSIDName"){
                }
                 else {
                }
                //console.log("Your current connected wifi SSID is " + ssid);
              },
              () => {
                //console.log("Cannot get current SSID!");
              }
            );
            }).catch(err => {
              //console.log("not permitted to enable location");
            });
        } 
        else 
        {
    //console.log("not granted");
    // Permission denied
        }
        // expected output: "Success!"
      });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to turn on a hotspot with a specific SSID and password programmatically on iOS and Android?

Answer (score -1):

There is no public API to control the [Wifi on iOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123022/how-to-turn-wifi-on-off-based-on-location/123025#123025).

Method [setEnabled](https://github.com/JuanSeBestia/react-native-wifi-reborn#setenabledenabled-boolean) is only for android.